# "Never mind" in American English and British English

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english, word-usage

Reading some forum pages about the meaning of the phrase *never mind*, I realized that there's a difference in usage of it, between American and British English. What's the difference in meaning of this phrase in American English and British English?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12752/what-is-the-difference-between-nevermind-and-never-mind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say there really isn't much difference in usage between American English and British English. In both dialects, it can be used to mean "it's alright", and dismissively to mean something like "shut up, I'm annoyed". A lot of it depends on tone of voice.

Answer (score 3):

Considering **@Snubian**'s answer, I think the phrase could be used both ways in both regions.
I don't see a particular UK/US distinction; rather, the difference depends on the mood of the speaker, as @Jez suggested.

I do notice a difference (but again, not a regional one) between transitive and intransitive use:

**Transitive** = *Disregard*

> **Fred:** I'm slightly worried about X
>   **Bill:** Never mind *that* - what about Y?

**Intransitive** = "*Oh well, that's a shame, but let's not worry about it*"

> **Fred:** So I'm afraid we'll have to have pizza, not tacos
>   **Bill:** Never mind. I like tacos.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to detect a subtle difference between typical usage in the UK and US.

US example:

> **Bill:** Hey, Fred, how would you like two free tickets to see Michael Bolton?
>
> **Fred:** Yeah, sounds cool! When's the show?
>
> **Bill:** Saturday night.
>
> **Fred:** Dang, I can't make it Saturday, I'll have to pass on the tickets.
>
> **Bill:** Aw, too bad.
>
> **Fred:** Never mind.

UK example:

> **Fred:** Hey, Bill, do you have those two
> Michael Bolton tickets you promised
> me?
>
> **Bill:** Oh, Fred, sorry mate, but the
> missus gave those to her sister.
>
> **Fred:** What?! But you promised them to
> me!
>
> **Bill:** Yeah, I know, but ...
>
> **Fred:** We've hired a babysitter and
> everything!
>
> **Bill:** I'm really sorry, Fred - look,
> let me make it up to you ...
>
> **Fred:** Oh, never mind! [storms off in a
> huff]